# If angular momentum is constant when there is zero torque, how come the rotational dynamics allow for a non-constant angular momentum?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, angular-velocity

The rotational dynamics are $$I\dot{\omega} = I\omega \times \omega + \tau$$
where $\tau$ is the torque, $\omega \in \mathbb{R}^3$ is the angular velocity of the rigid body, $\hat{.}$ is the hat operator, $I \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$ is the inertia matrix. If $\tau=0$, then we have $$I \dot{\omega}=I\omega \times \omega.$$ Under this constraint, it is possible for $\omega$ to be non-constant. This implies the angular momentum, $I \omega$ is non-constant. But zero torque is supposed to imply conservation of angular momentum. What is going on here?

My theory is that $\omega$ is in the body-frame coordinates. Is that the case? What would the rotational dynamics be in the world frame coordinates then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inertial-frame angular momentum ${\bf L}={\bf I}{\boldsymbol \omega}$  can be constant even when ${\boldsymbol \omega}$ is changing because ${\bf I}$ is only constant when viewed in the *body-fixed* frame. The ${\bf I}$ tensor is time dependent in the space-fixed inertial frame.